# Enabling scheduler statistics in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

The Linux kernel provide additional stats for each thread and uses a flag CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS to enable this fields. Is there any configuration file where I can enable this CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS or I can define it in any of the scheduling files (say sched_stats.h)?

Answer (score 1):

It's a kernel configuration option, you can set it by answering yes to `Collect scheduler statistics` when you run `make config`.